# Dedicate one physcial port to one virtual port in proxmox without libvirt

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, kvm, proxmox, macvlan

I simply need to dedicate 1 host physical port to 1 virtual port of guest without help of libvirt.

Host has:

- 2 physical interfaces: eth0 and eth1
- 1 virtual bridge(vmbr0), that include virtual interfaces of all VMs
- **eth0 is in bridge mode with vmbr0**. Thanks to that all guests and host are in the same subnet (192.168.247.0/24).

Here is my config of `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual
iface eth1 inet manual

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address 192.168.247.2
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.247.1
        bridge_ports eth0
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
```

eth1 must be connected to ISP modem. So eth1 will be exit to internet. I want to dedicate eth1 to virtual firewall that is one of the virtual machines in the host. And virtual firewall will do all routing job, not the host.

As far as I see for that task I must to use MacVTap (macvlan), but all guides that I saw was for KVM+libvirt, **and I don't have libvirt!** There is Proxmox who is doing all "user friendly tasks"

As you can see bellow right now there is only 1 VM enabled, it's interfaces tap101i0 and tap101i1, where tap101i0 suppose to be in vmbr0 and share the same subnet mask as eth0 of the host. And tap101i1 must be 100% bound with eth1 of the host, so it will be exit to internet.

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master vmbr0 state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:17:50:95:66 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:17:50:95:67 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: tap101i0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 06:97:77:30:cc:a7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: tap101i1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ce:b4:f3:40:38:0d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
8: vmbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:17:50:95:66 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the macvlan to achieve this.

1. Create a macvlan interface on eth1:

   ```
   ip link add link eth1 name macvlan1 type macvlan mode bridge
   ```
2. Assign an IP address to the macvlan interface. 
   This IP address will be used by the VM:

   ```
   ip addr add 192.168.247.3/24 dev macvlan1
   ```
3. Bring up the macvlan interface:

   ```
   ip link set macvlan1 up
   ```
4. Get the PID of the VM (replace `vm-name` with the actual name):

   ```
   ps aux | grep [v]m-name
   ```
5. Add the macvlan interface to the VM's network namespace
   (replace `PID` with the actual PID):

   ```
   ip link set macvlan1 netns PID
   ```
6. Bring up the macvlan interface inside the VM
   (again, replace the PID):

   ```
   ip netns exec PID ip link set macvlan1 up
   ```

Now, the VM should be able to use eth1 as if it was directly connected to it. The VM will have the IP address 192.168.247.3 and will be able to communicate with the internet through eth1.